# Not able to disable BG screen after a click

Tags: javascript, json, html, angularjs

I'm trying to disable the background screen after one click.But if click again there are multiple pop up has raised.How can i disable the background screen after a click.

this is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<html>

<li id="logical-resources" ng-click="showLogicalResourcesPool()"  ng-class="{'vrack-info-padding-top-9':dashboardInfo.workloads.length > 0,'vrack-info-padding-top-30':dashboardInfo.workloads.length == 0 || dashboardInfo.workloads == null}">

<span ng-click="showLogicalResourcesPool();" ng-hide="isLogicalResourcesDisable==false" ></span>

<span ng-show="isLogicalResourcesDisable==true" style="color:gray"></span>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
 $scope.showLogicalResourcesPool = function() { $scope.showDisableDone = 0;
 $rootScope.modalInstance = $modal.open({ templateUrl:
 vrmUi.getDashboardValue("LOGICAL_RESOURCES_URL"), backdrop:
 vrmUi.getDashboardValue("BACKDROP_STYLE_STATIC"), keyboard: false }); };
```

Comment: Where is your code???

Comment: Can you format your code and add more?  I'm not able to tell what you're attempting to do.

Comment: How can i add the code..I tried but not able to post.how can i differ my code from normal text

Comment: We need more code to help fully. But ... if your JS function "showLogicalResourcesPool()" opened new popup, you need to check, before to show, if another popup is already opened. In this case, you need to close them.

Comment: $scope.showLogicalResourcesPool = function() {
     $scope.showDisableDone = 0;
             $rootScope.modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: vrmUi.getDashboardValue("LOGICAL_RESOURCES_URL"),
            backdrop: vrmUi.getDashboardValue("BACKDROP_STYLE_STATIC"),
            keyboard: false
        });
    };

Comment: this is JS function..can u please tell me the exact solution to avoid opening multiple pop up

Comment: I found that error could be in js...

Comment: can u give me a correct js function..i'm not having any idea

Comment: Any one is there to help me?

Comment: Hi i need solution for this js. can anyone help me?

Comment: any one does know about this

Comment: Hi any have any idea on this issue?

Comment: Can i have help? i'm jusy stuck here for 3 days?